# How make animation only consider the final position?

Tags: unity, animation, animation-controller

I'm trying to make an energy indicator for a puzzle, and i decide to user animation to set the position of the red indicator(photo).

My first ideia is to make 9 animations, and for every black arrow i set the final position to the red indicator. And organizer in the animation controller.

But the main problem is, after every animation, the red indicator got to the first position, in the case the first arrow black, and then go the final position, because all the animation have the same position in the begin (0s).

How can i animation the trasition of red indicator to only got to the end position? Like, if the position of the red indicator was in the 7th black arrow and then go to 3th arrow. Is possible with animation?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an overly complicated solution for something you could do with a couple lines of script. Would you be interested in options that let you forego the animations, state control graph, and animator entirely?

Comment: I see how i can do it with code using Lerp. But i want always use unity functions like animation. Because every time a make something with code i see there's another option in unity funtions.